# Tab onto ASP button and press enter to fire button doesn't fire onClick

Tags: javascript, button, onclick, keypress

I have an asp button that is created server side and I have set its OnClientClick event to fire a Javascript function.
It renders on the page with the onClick event correctly containing the call to the Javascript function and when I click the button it all works as it should.

The problem occurs when I tab onto the button and press the enter key. It submits the form, but it doesn't fire the onclick event, so my Javascript isn't being called.

I have tried to assign an onKeyPress and onKeyDown to the button, but that's not worked.
It must be something simple that I've missed, but I'm just drawing a blank here.

Any help gratefully accepted, thanks.

Here is the html that is generated for the button:

```
    <input type="submit" name="SaveButtonTop" value="Save"
onclick="javascript:return ClickSubmitBtn();WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions(new WebForm_PostBackOptions(&quot;SaveButtonTop&quot;, &quot;&quot;, true, &quot;&quot;, &quot;&quot;, false, false))" id="SaveButtonTop" />
```

Comment: Aside: since JavaScript is the ONLY thing that can run in an onclick event you should leave out the "javascript:" part.

Comment: That makes sense, good point!

Answer (score 0):

You are using a SUBMIT button, therefore it will submit. You must cancel the default action of the button event in the function you are calling, or use a regular button, not a submit.

See: http://css-tricks.com/return-false-and-prevent-default/

Comment: Thanks for the response - I have managed to get it to produce a normal button now, but again, even with an onclientclick, an onkeypress and an onclick event that no longet posts back, it is acting the same.
If I click the button with the mouse, the onclick event calls my javascript, it hits my debugger and does everything correctly. But if I tab onto the button and press the enter key, it just posts the page back without doing anything client side. I was always under the impression that the enter key fired a normal click event, but I'm clearly mistaken. Any other ideas on this one?
Thanks

Comment: One trick is to prevent the enter=submit is have a hidden extra text field that does nothing.